# help on proving some property of cubic root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

Anyone can help to prove below expression

> $\omega^r$ and  $\omega^{2r}$ satisfy the equation $x^3 - 1=0$ for any positive integer $r$, where $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are non-real cube roots of unity.

Comment: Add some more dollar signs, please, so that your question is easier to read. I added a few for you already. If the "w" thing is supposed to denote a cube root of unity, you should say so.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Right now your question is almost unintelligible. You may wish to peruse our [basic MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial to learn how to typeset math here. Also, it would be nice if you could add where you encountered this problem and what you tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be any root of $x^3-1$ Then $a^3=1$. So $(a^r)^3=(a^3)^r=1^r=1$. This means $a^r$ is also a root of $x^3-1$.

To people who already know roots of unity, they will know the groups of "roots of unity" are cyclic. So tis is true in general.